# JQuery selector: get one of multiple class names, as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many divs in a page, like so:

```
<div class="formitem food-6 group-7">
//content of div
  <input type="checkbox"> //child of div
</div>

<div class="formitem food-7 group-7">
//content of div
  <input type="checkbox"> //child of div
</div>
```

When a checkbox is checked, I want to store the value of it's parent's unique class e.g "food-6" or "food-7" in a variable. I can get all the classes of the parent, like this:

```
parent = $(this).closest(".formitem").attr("class");
```

Which gives me `formitem food-7 group-7`.

How can I get "the one that starts with food-" ?

Comment: Since it looks like you're using this `food-7` class for computation instead of CSS, have you considered using `data-` attributes instead?

Answer (score 6):

Try a simple regex like

```
parent = $(this).closest(".formitem").attr("class").match(/\b(food-\d+)\b/)[1];
```

Comment: in this case both are same... just went with the grouped item

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression

```
...attr("class").match(/food-\d+/)
```

if you want just the number

```
.match(/food-(\d+)/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    var parent_class = '';
    parent_class = $(this).parent('div').attr('class').match(/food-\d+/);
    alert(parent_class);
});
```